# Ajax jquery how to keep content after page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery and ajax. here's an idea of the code i'll be using. Suppose that i refresh the page after getting the response. (which in this case is a form). I lose the content completely. How can I keep/cache/store the data response in a variable so that after I press on f5 or refresh the same content reloads.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form.php",
        data: {name: "John", email: "michigan@usa.com"},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#output").html(data);
        }
    })
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to store the data in some manner, some of your options are:

- Database
- Xml
- Text file
- Session
- Cookies
- etc.

To name just a few.

Once you post your information to the server, you will store it somwhere, then when you hit F5 or refresh, you will check if there is data stored and populate your page with it.

How you implement this will depend on the server side languages you are using.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ if you need jq solution only. But...

But best way for "keep content after page refresh" - keep it by server side